# Mikrotik Profile Activation Failing With No Such Command Error in PHP

Tags: php, mikrotik, router-os

So, I have the following function to activate a Profile for a registered user using the RouterOS php library

```
 public function activateProfile($username)
    {
        $activationQuery = new Query(
            '/tool/user-manager/user/create-and-activate-profile',
            [
                '=user=' . $username,
                '=customer=admin',
                '=profile=profile1',
            ]
        );
        $response = $this->query($activationQuery)->read(false);
        print("Activating Profile...");
        print_r($response);
    }
```

But I keep getting the error message below

```
Activating Profile...Array ( [0] => !trap [1] => =message=no such command [2] => !done )
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Quick Reply

You cannot pass attribute word `user`, you need to pass the number that identifies the user instead. Better to first create and then create-and-activate-profile as [documentation](https://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:User_Manager#Configuration_Examples) says.

#### Explanation

RouterOS APi [command words](https://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:API#Command_word) closely follow CLI.

Your command word is `/tool/user-manager/user/create-and-activate-profile` .

Your attributes words are `=user`,`=customer`,`=profile`.

Yo can compare with CLI and wiki from User_Manager, =user= is available

```
[admin@106] /tool user-manager user> create-and-activate-profile                                    

<numbers> -- List of item numbers
customer -- 
profile --
```

#### Demostration

```
/tool/user-manager/user/add
=customer=admin
=disabled=no
=password=test
=shared-users=1
=username=test

<<< /tool/user-manager/user/add
<<< =customer=admin
<<< =disabled=no
<<< =password=test
<<< =shared-users=1
<<< =username=test
<<< 
>>> !done
>>> =ret=*1
>>> 

<<< /tool/user-manager/user/create-and-activate-profile
<<< =numbers=*1
<<< =customer=admin
<<< =profile=a
<<< 
>>> !done
>>>
```